# Powershell Get Active logged in user in local machine

Tags: windows, powershell, users

I am trying to get currently logged in users who has active session.

In the task manager, the list is crystal clear that there are two user sessions and one is active.

I want to query the same via Powershell. 
I tried few of the available commands
`Get-WmiObject Win32_LoggedOnUser | Select Antecedent -Unique` which lists lot more users than I can even see [domain joined computer]

I am looking for the query which can give results exactly like Task Manager.
[image]

Comment: What about `query user`?

Comment: @duenni seems right way. anyway to parse and get `Active users`. Seems like it's string output

Comment: Maybe this can help you http://superuser.com/q/587737/378809

Comment: AFAIK there isn't a native way via PowerShell, I've looked for it in the past. See [Powershell get a value from 'query user' and not the headers etc](http://superuser.com/questions/587737/powershell-get-a-value-from-query-user-and-not-the-headers-etc?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @MagicallyDelicous, I am actually trying to execute some scripts in remote machine using remote powershell. If there's no active user, I am trying to reboot the machine.

Comment: Reddy - Get ready when it's time for spaghetti and remind me to get my machete so I can chop, chop, chop... psyche... What's the status on this? Did you read my comments too?

Comment: @MagicallyDelicous I have done it differently http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42711592/getting-the-logged-in-user-in-powershell

This works in all machines and not lang dependent and gives the right results

Comment: Oh, so you used some C# code in PS with the `Add-Type`... that was my second guess... **NOT**!!

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I do it.  It doesn't work for rdp sessions though.

```
$out = query session | where {$_ -match 'console'}
$array = $out -split('\s+')
$consoleuser = $array[1]
```

Or:

```
$consoleuser = query session | select-string console | foreach { -split $_ } | 
  select -index 1
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue with `Get-WmiObject Win32_LoggedOnUser | Select Antecedent -Unique` is that it shows all sessions even those that have been closed since the last time the computer rebooted. The easiest way to poll sessions is unfortunately using the old executable query.exe.

You can convert the output of query.exe to objects using a bit of regex:

```
$Computer = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$Users = query user /server:$Computer 2>&1

$Users = $Users | ForEach-Object {
    (($_.trim() -replace ">" -replace "(?m)^([A-Za-z0-9]{3,})\s+(\d{1,2}\s+\w+)", '$1  none  $2' -replace "\s{2,}", "," -replace "none", $null))
} | ConvertFrom-Csv

foreach ($User in $Users)
{
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ComputerName = $Computer
        Username = $User.USERNAME
        SessionState = $User.STATE.Replace("Disc", "Disconnected")
        SessionType = $($User.SESSIONNAME -Replace '#', '' -Replace "[0-9]+", "")
    } 
}
```

Which will give you output like this:

```
ComputerName Username SessionState SessionType
------------ -------- ------------ -----------
BSMITH-LT    bobsm    Active       console
```

Taking it a lot further in to a function:

```
function Convert-QueryToObjects
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [Alias('QueryToObject')]
    [OutputType([PSCustomObject])]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false,
                   ValueFromPipeline = $true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
                   Position = 0)]
        [Alias('ComputerName', 'Computer')]
        [string]
        $Name = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    )

    Process
    {
        Write-Verbose "Running query.exe against $Name."
        $Users = query user /server:$Name 2>&1

        if ($Users -like "*No User exists*")
        {
            # Handle no user's found returned from query.
            # Returned: 'No User exists for *'
            Write-Error "There were no users found on $Name : $Users"
            Write-Verbose "There were no users found on $Name."
        }
        elseif ($Users -like "*Error*")
        {
            # Handle errored returned by query.
            # Returned: 'Error ...<message>...'
            Write-Error "There was an error running query against $Name : $Users"
            Write-Verbose "There was an error running query against $Name."
        }
        elseif ($Users -eq $null -and $ErrorActionPreference -eq 'SilentlyContinue')
        {
            # Handdle null output called by -ErrorAction.
            Write-Verbose "Error action has supressed output from query.exe. Results were null."
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Verbose "Users found on $Name. Converting output from text."

            # Conversion logic. Handles the fact that the sessionname column may be populated or not.
            $Users = $Users | ForEach-Object {
                (($_.trim() -replace ">" -replace "(?m)^([A-Za-z0-9]{3,})\s+(\d{1,2}\s+\w+)", '$1  none  $2' -replace "\s{2,}", "," -replace "none", $null))
            } | ConvertFrom-Csv

            Write-Verbose "Generating output for $($Users.Count) users connected to $Name."

            # Output objects.
            foreach ($User in $Users)
            {
                Write-Verbose $User
                if ($VerbosePreference -eq 'Continue')
                {
                    # Add '| Out-Host' if -Verbose is tripped.
                    [PSCustomObject]@{
                        ComputerName = $Name
                        Username = $User.USERNAME
                        SessionState = $User.STATE.Replace("Disc", "Disconnected")
                        SessionType = $($User.SESSIONNAME -Replace '#', '' -Replace "[0-9]+", "")
                    } | Out-Host
                }
                else
                {
                    # Standard output.
                    [PSCustomObject]@{
                        ComputerName = $Name
                        Username = $User.USERNAME
                        SessionState = $User.STATE.Replace("Disc", "Disconnected")
                        SessionType = $($User.SESSIONNAME -Replace '#', '' -Replace "[0-9]+", "")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and now you can do things like: `Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like "SERVER*"} | Convert-QueryToObjects | ? {$_.SessionState -eq 'Active'}`

Comment: the only problem is. The `quser` returns output in local language. This will be a problem if one wants to run on remote machines which might has different lang

Comment: You can modify the function to handle different languages but there sadly no real alternative ways to get the information you need. The only viable pure PowerShell method is to check for running explorer.exe processes on the remote machine but that doesn't distinguish between active and disconnected sessions.

That said, now may be the time to consider standardizing the installation language of your servers and having users make use of Set-WinUILanguageOverride for their personal UI language needs.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with:

```
get-wmiobject -Class Win32_Computersystem | select Username
```

Comment: It gives me empty result when I execute in remote machine from RDP :(

Comment: the wmi query only gets localy signed in users, to get rdp sessions try "qwinsta"
here's a script i've got with one google search https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-script-to-Find-d2ba4252

Answer (score 2):

```bash
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -f 'Name="explorer.exe"'  |%  getowner  |% user
```

Comment: Surrounding this piece of code by some explanation would seriously improve your answer.

Comment: This answer would indeed greatly benefits from some explanation/context. BUT I think it offers a new and nicer way to query currently logged-in users by searching for all Explorer.exe process and retrieving the user associated with it. It's quite clever actually, I like it.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but this is how I do it. I get the output from quser, replace tabs with commas and then convert the data from CSV to an object.

```
$QUserToRichObject = ((Invoke-Expression quser) -replace '\s{2,}', ',' | ConvertFrom-Csv)

If($QUserToRichObject){

    $UserSessions = @()

    ForEach($Record in $QUserToRichObject){

        # If the active session, remove the '>' character from Username value
        If($Record.USERNAME -Like ">*"){$Record.USERNAME = ($Record.USERNAME -Replace ">", "")}

        $UserSessions += @{
            Username        = [string]$Record.USERNAME
            SessionName     = [string]$Record.SESSIONNAME
            ID              = [string]$Record.ID
            State           = [string]$Record.STATE
            Idle            = [string]$Record.'IDLE TIME'
            LogonTime       = [string]$Record.'LOGON TIME'
        }
    }
}

$UserSessions

<#
Outputs:
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                           
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                           
ID                             1                                                                                                                                                                               
SessionName                    console                                                                                                                                                                         
Idle                           none                                                                                                                                                                            
LogonTime                      04/11/2019 14:01                                                                                                                                                                
Username                       SomeUsername                                                                                                                                                                 
State                          Active
#>
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on alex's interesting solution; this is a more "PowerShell native" way to do it (though WMI and CIM are native in a way).

```
# This will get unique users that have any process running on the computer
Get-process -IncludeUserName | Select-Object UserName -Unique
```

This solution will include all system accounts too that are running processes on the computer, but that is fairly east to filter out if necessary.

I have verified that this also gets users connected with RDP on a Windows Server core instance too (which will not have an explorer shell running usually).
Mind that it will also get users having for example an active PowerShell remote session too since that also creates a process for the user.
Though depending on the use case, this might be useful too.